# Update multiple rows in a single SQL Server query - in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-update

I am using VBA to update an Access database with the following code:

```
For i = 1 To imax
    strSql = "UPDATE Products SET Price ='" & vArray(i, 2) & "' WHERE ID = '" &   vArray(i, 1) & "';"
    connDB.Execute (strSql)
Next i
```

That works but can be very slow since there are between 5,000 and 10,000 rows to update (imax).

Is there a way to use a single SQL statement instead?

I've tried Jatin's suggestion below. Unfortunately it doesn't fly on my side (a try on the first three rows below):

```
UPDATE p SET p.Price = x.SetValue FROM Products p INNER JOIN (
SELECT '149' AS SetValue, 'P100005' AS WhereValue  UNION ALL 
SELECT '129' AS SetValue, 'P100001' AS WhereValue  UNION ALL 
SELECT '99' AS SetValue, 'P100002' AS WhereValue  ) AS x ON p.ID = x.WhereValue;
```

Comment: So, you are using one Access file to update another? Or you are connecting to SQL Server?

Comment: Do you want to run that update only once or that code belongs to a feature in some application?

Comment: you can hold all the `ID's` in a single variable using for loop, then you can fire your `SQL Query` by using the condition `ID in (your ID's)`

Comment: Wow, already so many answers! Thank you!

Comment: @gofr1 Data come from an excel file, and yes I connect to a SQL server

Comment: @ A_Name That sounds like the solution proposed below by Jatin. It sounds good actually. Is it possible to do it with 10,000 IDs though? The SQL query would be huge!

Comment: @Miguel The code belongs to an application and is to be used every now and again. Do you think about stored procedure or similar things? (I read about that but never touched)

Comment: Yes you could use stored procedures @Phil, but the problem here is how to send you big array of data to the data base engine. Here do you get all the data for the vArray? From a file, from the data base or from other source?

Comment: @miguelbgouveia Data originally come from the database. They get extracted in VBA in an array. The array is then processed and "columns" get modified (actually 5 columns, I've simplified the query on the initial post) before being sent back to the Database.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you get from the DB 5000 to 10000 values  and extract them to an array. Then modify around 5 of them. Then process the update in DB for all, the modified and the unmodified ones. Why don't you just create updates only for the ones that were modified? This way you resolve your performance issue.

Comment: @miguelbgouveia True, the process is not optimal. But I meant that 5 columns get updated, so 5 * 5000 to 5* 10000 rows. The update process is not that straightforward and is difficult to touch without rewriting it fully. It has actually been optimized to avoid calculating the values for each rows when possible and I don't think it could be updated much more (it could be that all rows need update). For now, improvement seem difficult using Access and we will stick to this slower performance until we can use SQL server and hopefully use Jatin's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not expert to VBA, but something like below will do the task.

```
strValues = "INNER JOIN (VALUES "
For i = 1 To imax    
    strValues = strValues & IIF(i = 1,"",",") & "('" & vArray(i, 2) & "', '" & vArray(i, 1) & "')"
Next i
strValues = strValues & " ) AS x(SetValue, WhereValue) ON p.ID = x.WhereValue "
strSql = "UPDATE p SET p.Price = x.SetValue FROM Products p " & strValues
connDB.Execute (strSql)
```

below is an alternate solution, it builds value table with UNION ALL.

```
strValues = "INNER JOIN ("
For i = 1 To imax    
    strValues = strValues & vbCrLf & "SELECT '" & vArray(i, 2) & "' AS SetValue, '" & vArray(i, 1) & "' AS WhereValue " & IIF(i = imax,""," UNION ALL ") 'skip Union All for last entry
Next i
strValues = strValues & " ) AS x ON p.ID = x.WhereValue "
strSql = "UPDATE p SET p.Price = x.SetValue FROM Products p " & strValues
connDB.Execute (strSql)
```

Comment: Thanks Jatin, that looks great. I will try it. Hopefully it will work with such a large SQL string. PS: there might be a missing "strValues &"  and strValues must surely be used inside the Query. I'll play with that piece of code

Comment: @Phil I have corrected it. Let us know whatever your finding is.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm likely to try it tomorrow, must finish other things at work now. Sure, I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this bit of code. It appears I was not too clear. Our application is actually supposed to work with both Access and SQL Server.  And right now, I am doing the Access bit. The code above does not work for Access. I thought Access SQL would be closer to SQL Server... I keep it for later use in TSQL as it appears Access does not offer easy batch update... @Jatin I accept your answer since it gives the right logic to follow. And hopefully I'll be able to implement it soon

Comment: @Phil, I have added a modified version to use with Access database, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the addition of Access code! Unfortunately I don't get it running. I'll give the SQL statement in a separate post for clarity sake

Comment: I've added the SQL statement obtained from a try on the first three rows in the original post.

Comment: No error is shown, but nothing happens. Actually, VBA doesn't seem to show database errors (I might miss something here). To make sure, I have wrapped the ConnDB.Execute(strSql) in two 'debug.print'. Only the first one shows

Comment: @Phil, I have tried to test this with access, but access has limitation and it do not support this kind of query syntax, also access only supports single statement at a time. Looks like for access the best way is what you have right now - single update at a time.

Comment: Yes it looks like Access is troublesome for that purpose. Then our customer will have to do a manual update and wait a bit for updates since he wishes to  have both Access and SQL. I'll keep the SQL in the loop then, at least for the Access version. And your SQL version will be hopefully soon in use. Thanks a lot for your time and invaluable help Man!

Comment: By the way, there is a possibility with Access to do similar actions to CASE WHEN in SQL by using the SWITCH function. I've tested but its major drawback is that it can only contain a few (around 10) conditions. so, not really useful for batch update (unless making things more complicated than they should be)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but there is not such a statement for this one. You have to do it like this in this case.

Comment: Ok Herr Pülsinger, but there must be a more performant solution